# How to create ClickOnce shortcuts for a Visual Studio 2010 project in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1, clickonce

I am working on one of our older projects that still uses Visual Studio 2010. I need to make our Winforms application auto-update, so I'm using ClickOnce. However, even though it's configured to create both a "start menu" shortcut as well as desktop shortcut, no shortcuts are created. (I am running Windows 8.1.)

Is there a work around for this?

What I've tried is as follows: I noticed that if I run the .application file directly, it does update, so it appears to be working, but I don't know if it will work properly for our customers, and I'm struggling to find relevant info online. We have customers using Windows 7 and Windows 8.

I don't understand the difference between the .application file and the shortcut that should be created. Will giving them the .application file work, or is it something totally different to the shortcut?

Comment: it seems you are asking 2 questions: one is about the missing shortcut, the other is `will distributing .application file alone works?`. Do not ask multiple questions in one post, especially the title only mention the first one.

Comment: I'll edit the question to clarify. As far as I understand, the .application file is the same as the shortcut. It's only two questions if you choose to be pedantic.

Comment: :). I'm not too sure myself. So I'm afraid of relying on it, because I might be wrong. I don't want to end up in a situation where it only "works on my machine".